# Move with multiple elements by jQuery ui sortable()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create script, that will allow me to sort some elements simultaneously with other ones. I created simple jsfiddle to demonstrate what exactly I am trying. I have 2 lines of elements with numbers 1-5, but sortable is only top line.

```
<div class="demo1 demo">
    <div id="sortable">
        <div class="test">1</div>
        <div class="test">2</div>
        <div class="test">3</div>
        <div class="test">4</div>
        <div class="test">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="demo2 demo">
    <div>
        <div class="test">1</div>
        <div class="test">2</div>
        <div class="test">3</div>
        <div class="test">4</div>
        <div class="test">5</div>
    </div>
</div>

$("#sortable").sortable({

});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/18fdku10/2/)
My goal is create script, that will move with bottom div simultaneously as is moving top div.

Answer (score 0):

I found working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k3fFG/) wery clean and usefull solution

```
var lst, pre;

$(".sortlist").sortable({
    start:function(event, ui){
        pre = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        lst = $(this).attr('id');
        post = ui.item.index();
        other = (lst == 'list1') ? 'list2' : 'list1';
        //Use insertBefore if moving UP, or insertAfter if moving DOWN
        if (post > pre) {
            $('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +pre+ ')').insertAfter('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +post+ ')');
        }else{
            $('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +pre+ ')').insertBefore('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +post+ ')');
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```